# WorksheetFunction.Match used in a temporary worksheet issue

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I'm using the  `WorksheetFunction.Match` in a temporary workbook.

```
Dimen = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("A15"), temp.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A200"))
colNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("A15"), temp.Sheets(1).Range("32:32"))

Dimen1 = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("A16"), temp.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A200"))
colNum1 = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("A16"), temp.Sheets(1).Range("33:33"))

Dimen2 = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("A17"), temp.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A200"))
colNum2 = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("A17"), temp.Sheets(1).Range("34:34"))

Dimen3 = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("A18"), temp.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A200"))
 colNum3 = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("A18"), temp.Sheets(1).Range("35:35"))

Dimen4 = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("A19"), temp.Sheets(1).Range("A1:200"))
colNum4 = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("A19"), temp.Sheets(1).Range("36:36"))
```

The last two lines:

```
Dimen4 = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("A19"), temp.Sheets(1).Range("A1:200")) 
colNum4 = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("A19"), temp.Sheets(1).Range("36:36"))
```

it comes up with the 1004 error, I do not know the reason for that error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Dimen4 = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("A19"), temp.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A200")) 
colNum4 = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("A19"), temp.Sheets(1).Range("A36").EntireRow)
```

and probably change it in all lines. It would fail everywhere I guess..

The reasons are:

- `Range("A1:200")` is invalid syntax

As DG pointed out in the comment below, `Range("1:1").Address` does work, it is not at all invalid!

Comment: `Range("1:1")` isn't invalid, e.g., typing `? Range("1:1").Address` in the Immediate Window yields "$1:$1." It refers to the first row.

Comment: @Doug Glancy, you were right, I got it all wrong. Amended - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the error that occurs when the the `Match` function does not find a match.  Since you're not supplying the third argument to `Match`, the problem could be that: a) the values in the range you're searching are not sorted in ascending order, and/or, b) the value you're searching for is less than all the values in the range you're searching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim Result As Variant
If Not VBA.IsError(Application.Match(...)) Then
    Result = Application.Match(...)
End If
```

This tries the match and if there is an error on the function it will not assign a result.

[WorksheetFunction.Match Method (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx)